# Adding data to data table without filling the column names C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add data from an excel spreadsheet to a data table, I am getting the data no worries and adding it to the tables within the datasets but when I do add it, it fills the column names with the top row. I have tried to set the column names but then it just cuts off the top row of data.
I am fairly new to C#, I'm pretty sure I need to alter the fill method **objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1,tableName);** but have no idea how to go about it.

```
    public DataSet readExcel()
    {
        int x = 0;
        string[] Individal_Runs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\testfiles");
        DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet();
        int iso = 0;
        foreach (string s in Individal_Runs)
        {
            x++;
            try
            {
                String theConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + s + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml";
                OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(theConnString);
                objConn.Open();

                string[] sheetnames = GetExcelSheetNames(String.Format("{0}", s));
                int y = 0;
                int z = 0;
                string tableName;
                bool looponce = false;

                foreach (string sn in sheetnames)
                {

                    OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sn.ToString()), objConn);
                    OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();

                    if( looponce == false)
                    {
                        tableName = string.Format("isolations_{0}", iso);
                        objDataset1.Tables.Add(tableName);
                        objDataset1.Tables[tableName].NewRow();
                        DataRow newRow = objDataset1.Tables[tableName].NewRow();

                        objDataset1.Tables[tableName].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);

                        looponce = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tableName = string.Format("isolations_{0}_{1}", iso,y);
                        objDataset1.Tables.Add(tableName);
                        DataRow newRow = objDataset1.Tables[tableName].NewRow();

                        objDataset1.Tables[tableName].Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0);

                        y++;
                    }

                    objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
                    objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1,tableName);

                    int cols = objDataset1.Tables[tableName].Columns.Count;
                    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
                    {
                        objDataset1.Tables[tableName].Columns[i].ColumnName = i.ToString();
                    }
                    z++;
                }
                iso++;
            }
```

Comment: If the first line of your sheet doesn't contain the column names then you can tell OleDb to treat the first line as data changing your connectionstring with HDR=NO; see https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/

Comment: See connection strings :" HDR=NO   https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: Fixed. 
theConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + s + "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';";